# Why do I have 3 threads here?

Tags: java

Well, I've come to my wit's end: I would say it is 2 threads here. Why should I have three I don't know.

```
public class ParallelProgramming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thrd firstThread = new Thrd("FirstThread.txt");
        firstThread.start();
        Thrd secondThread = new Thrd("SecondThread.txt");        
        secondThread.start();
    } // main
} // class



public class Thrd extends Thread {
String file;
    public Thrd(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(){
        <read the file line by line>
    }
}
```

Comment: What creates those 2 extra threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the two threads are started by the main thread which is created when you start the application (in some cases, it's called UI thread too).

This thread runs `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

In every java application there is a main thread. It executes the program. It can create new threads as well.